# Azure API Management: Validate-Content with nullable properties

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management

I want to validate the JSON Request-Body in API Management with the [Validate content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies#validate-content) policy.

Some of the JSON properties shall support null-values.
Therefore I specified this in OpenApi:
*nullable: true*

But API Management ignores it.
How can I validate the body with null-values?

Policy:

```
<inbound>
    <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
        <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
    </validate-content>
    <base />
</inbound>
```

OpenApi:

```
    paths:
      /sample:
        post:
          summary: Sample
          description: Sample
          operationId: sample
          requestBody:
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'
          responses:
            '200':
              description: OK
    components:
      schemas:
        Customer:
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: integer
              format: int64
              example: '100000.0'
            username:
              type: string
              example: fehguy
            country:
              type: string
              nullable: true
              example: Lorem Ipsum
          example:
            id: '123.0'
            username: fehguy
            country: Lorem Ipsum
```

Request-Body:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "username":"fehguy",
  "country": null
}
```

Response-Body:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Body of the request does not conform to the definition Customer, which is associated with the content type application/json. Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line: 4, Position: 19" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is working on a fix:

> Engineering team is working on fix but there is no clear date yet

Workaround:

```
    country:
      anyOf:
        - type: "string"
        - type: "null"
      example: Lorem Ipsum
```